# Regex - Compare number with Constant

Tags: regex

If I like to match all numbers which are smaller than 2000, I use the Regex

```
    [01]{1}[0-9]{3}
```

If I like to match all numbers between 1 and 5 I use the expression

```
    [2-4]{1}
```

But what if I want to match all numbers between 5 and 123 ???

Is there a syntax for that?

Comment: Regular expressions are for matching patterns, not checking numeric values. Find a likely string with the regex, then check its numeric value in whatever your host language is (PHP, whatever).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match numbers > 5 and < 123, try:

```
[6-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-2]
```

For more information, take a look at: [Matching Numeric Ranges with a Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html)

Answer (score 1):

Break it up into different parts:

[6-9]|[1-9]\d|1[0-1]\d|12[0-2]

Answer (score 1):

If I needed to do this I would probably use this:

```
([^0-9]+)
```

Then parse the capture group as an integer (unless you are in a dynamic language when it will already be one ) and you can perform whatever numeric operations you want to on it.